# OpenGL Converting from busy vertex buffer to element buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, voxel

If you look at my history you can see some more context for what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm trying to draw multiple cubes with an element buffer without using instancing but for the sake of simplicity i'll use quads drawn with triangles.

If I have a VBO my array would look like below:

```
float cubeVertices[] = {
        //FRONT
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, //front top left
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, //front bottom left
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, //front top right

        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, //front top right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, //front bottom left
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f //front bottom right
    };
```

And converted to an element buffer it looks like:

```
float cubeVertices[] = {
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, //front top left
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, //front top right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, //front bottom left
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f //front bottom right
    };
    
    unsigned int cubeIndices[] = {
        0, 2, 1, //FRONT
        1, 2, 3
    };
```

But what do I do if I want to draw multiple? **(WITHOUT INSTANCING)**

For a VBO it seems simple enough

```
float cubeVertices[] = {
        //FRONT            translate(x, y, z)
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0, 0,//front top left
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0, 0,//front bottom left
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0, 0,//front top right

        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0, 0,//front top right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0, 0,//front bottom left
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0, 0,//front bottom right

        //FRONT            translate(x, y, z)
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 1, 1,//front top left
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 1, 1,//front bottom left
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 1, 1,//front top right

        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 1, 1,//front top right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 1, 1,//front bottom left
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 1, 1,//front bottom right
    };
```

Where each face is moved by the translate of (x y z) like `model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(x, y, z))`
But this has a lot of duplicate data like repeating the translation 6 times per quad and writing the vertex drawn locations twice per quad and an extra 2 duplicate vertices per quad.
Now imagine that for more advanced models and it seems like the waste of memory would get quite large.

So how do I convert the above to an element buffer? Ideally without duplicating data obviously.
I'll write some code/pseudo code to help explain what I'm after.

```
float cubeVertices[] = {
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, //front top left
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, //front top right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, //front bottom left
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f //front bottom right
    };
    
    unsigned int cubeIndices[] = {
        0, 2, 1, //FRONT
        1, 2, 3
    };
    
    unsigned int cubeLocations[] = {
        0, 0, 0,
        1, 1, 1
    };

for (int loc = 0; loc < 2; ++loc)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
             //VERTEX COORDS             //MODEL LOCATION
        Draw(cubeVertices[cubeIndices[i]], cubeLocations[loc]);
    }
}

**But done in one draw call, e.g. a simple mesh (Not instancing)**
```

The above would generates a memory efficient version of the VBO as an element array
Not sure how well I've articulated what I'm after is but I've tried my best to provide an explanation of my goal.

Think of a basic minecraft clone where all the unneeded drawn faces really starts to add up and instancing no longer works so meshing is now required.

Comment: "*But what do I do if I want to draw multiple? (WITHOUT INSTANCING)*" That's what instancing is *for*. Well, it's not for drawing quads; that's not good for performance. Just build a list of quads and render them. But the broad kind of thing you're doing is why instancing exists.

Comment: "*Now imagine that for more advanced models and it seems like the waste of memory would get quite large.*" The only reason you have duplicated data is because you're specifying the transform per-vertex. In real models, each vertex is its own data, and transforms apply to the model as a whole. Models are not made from some prototype quad or triangle, with each being transformed into position.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm trying to make a very basic minecraft clone.
They don't use instancing because there are faces that aren't shown and are removed and thats why meshing is needed. An instance would create the whole cube and when you've got enough chunks/cubes instancing just doesn't cut it anymore.
A 32x32x32 chunk has 32768 cubes and so considering chunks go up, down, left, right the unnecessarily drawn faces is very large

Comment: I am aware of how Minecraft renders. My point is that what you're trying to do is pointless. You shouldn't have "here's quad data" and "here's translations to where I want the quad to appear". Your buffer should simply have "the location for this quad", which already has the translation applied. Minecraft doesn't have your "translate" data, and for good reason.